# Prove Finite Language

Tags: discrete-mathematics, formal-languages, automata

Consider a countable alphabet $A = \{a_{1},a_{2},... \}$. Let $L_{k}$ be the language over $A$ consisting of those words $w$ such that the sum of the subscripts of the letters in $w$ is equal to $k$. Show that $L_{k}$ is finite.

I have tried:

- $A = a_{1}$ implies $L(a_{1})$ is finite.
- $A = a_{2}$ implies $L(a_{2})$ is finite.
- ...
- $A = a_{n}$ implies $L(a_{n})$ is finite.

Therefore the union: $L(a_{1}) \cup  L(a_{2}) \cup \cdots \cup L(n)$ is finite.

Am I doing this right or is there a more formal and better way to solve it?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're doing. Why are you restricting $A$ to a single character? And what is $L(a_1)$? Also, please use MathJax to make your posts more readable.

Comment: Be sure to note that "countable" does not mean "finite."  There could be an infinite number of symbols in $A$, in which case the fact that languages corresponding to each individual $a_k$ are finite does not imply that their union is finite (since there is an infinite number of them).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since each number $k$ has $2^{k-1}$ distinct [compositions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_%28combinatorics%29), $L_{k}$ will contain $2^{k-1}$ elements. Since for any $n ∈ \mathbb{N}$, $2^{n-1} ∈ \mathbb{N}$, it follows that $L_{n}$ must be finite.